# Truncated convolution algorithm

Tags: ds.algorithms, fourier-analysis

Suppose I have $n+1$-dimensional vectors $a$ and $b$. For each $i = 0, \dots, n$, I also have integers $0 \leq j_0(i) \leq j_1(i) \leq i$. I want to compute the following variant of a convolution:

$$
c_i = \sum_{j_0(i) \leq j \leq j_1(i)} a_j b_{i-j}
$$

If $j_0(i) = 0, j_1(i) = i$ for all $i$ this is a standard convolution, so you can do this via FFT in time $O(n \log n)$.

Are there any good algorithms for this when $j_0, j_1$ are arbitrary?

Comment: You're out by one I think. Both $a_0$ and $a_n$ are potentially referenced which means $a$ must have n+1 elements.

Comment: @user10310 you're right, I fixed it.